# issue with printing a table in php/mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

So basically my code isnt working here. The confusing part is that at a bare minimum it should be printing the table header, which it is not doing.

here is my function

```
public function getUsers(){
    global $connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbname, $connectstr_dbpassword, $connectstr_dbusername;
    $link=mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);



    echo ("
         <table border='1'>
         <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         </tr>

    ");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo(
            "<tr>" .
            "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>".
            "</tr>"

        );
    }


    echo "</table>";
}
```

Pretty new to php and I feel as if the answer is really simple, any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it throwing a error? Add these to the top
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: First check whether you're calling `getUsers()` method correctly or not.

Comment: always check if your mysql connection is not failed. there is a lot of example for that

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is that `user` over user. Try and see if resolve. If not try this code:

[TRY Save the content of the function in another file and just make an echo to see if the function is called]

```
public function getUsers(){
    global $connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbname, $connectstr_dbpassword, $connectstr_dbusername;
    $link = mysqli_connect($connectstr_dbhost, $connectstr_dbusername, $connectstr_dbpassword,$connectstr_dbname) or die('Não foi possível conectar');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = $link->query($sql);

    echo "
         <table border='1'>
         <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Username</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         </tr>

    ";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>" .
                "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>".
                "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>".
                "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>".
                "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>".
                "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>".
            "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: `\`user\`` is correct, `'user'` is not. Table and column names should not be wrapped in single quotes. Moreover, this part of the question, *The confusing part is that at a bare minimum it should be printing the table header, which it is not doing.* suggests that OP might not even called this method in the code.

Comment: if the sql statement is broken the code above not run.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the problem was I had not imported the database class.